# Como obtener elemento selecionado con click (id y posicion)

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy intentando hacer unas cosillas con DOM y se me ha planteado un problema al que , a priori , no encuentro solucion .

Dado un codigo HTML cualquiera , me gustaria obtener el tipo de elemento (div,button,table...) y su posicion.

Obtener el tipo de elemento con el target es facil , su posicion no tanto.

Pongo un ejemplo :

Si yo pincho en esta lista "Coffe" , con el target obtengo "LI" que es el objeto de Coffe , hasta ahi perfecto , pero ¿Como puedo yo trabajar con ese objeto LI en concreto ? Me refiero , como puedo , por ejemplo , modificar su contenido ?

Porque para modificar su contenido tengo varias opciones :

- document.getElementsByTagName("tag")[posicion] : Y claro no tengo la posicion.
- document.getElementById("id").innerHTML :Estoy trabajando con html sin id's.

¿Alguna idea? ¿Deberia de poner obligatoriamente id's? Me parece un atraso.

Muchas gracias de nuevo.

```js
  if (e.srcElement){
   tag = e.srcElement.tagName;
  }else{ (e.target)
     tag = e.target.type;
  }
 
  console.log("El elemento selecionado ha sido " + tag);
```

```html
 <ul> <!-- Primer ul -->
    <li>Coffee</li>
   <ul> <!-- Segundo ul -->
    <li>Beer</li>
       <ul> <!-- Tercer ul -->
     <li>Coffee</li>
     <li>Tea</li>
     <li>Milk</li>
      </ul>
    <li>Cola</li>
    <li>Water</li>
   </ul> 
    <li>Juice</li>
    <li>Wine</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: ¿Si el elemento que te interesa no tiene id, que otro criterio podrías usar para distinguirlo de otros?

Comment: Veo que buscas las mismas respuestas que yo @EdwinDalorzo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas pudiendo obtener `event.target.type` es porque ya tienes acceso al objeto que recibió el evento (en este caso `event.target`). Por lo tanto puedes manipular dicho objeto haciendo por ejemplo `event.target.innerText = "Seleccionado";`.

```js
function cambiar(event) {
  var tag = event.srcElement ? event.srcElement.tagName : event.target.type;
  document.getElementById('seleccionado').innerText = "El elemento selecionado ha sido " + tag;
  event.target.innerHTML += "<ul><li>Agregado</li></ul>";
}
```

```html
<div id="seleccionado"></div>
<ul onclick="cambiar(event)">
  <!-- Primer ul -->
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <ul>
    <!-- Segundo ul -->
    <li>Beer</li>
    <ul>
      <!-- Tercer ul -->
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Cola</li>
    <li>Water</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li>Wine</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias .Si me lo permites , me gustaria hacerte una pregunta mas .¿De que manera puedo por ejemplo añadir un nuevo LI al objeto ya selecionado ? Porque tag no guarda nada y no puedo pasar directamente el event.target an appendChild . Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Con este cambio puedes agregar sub-niveles. Siempre el Html que agregas tiene que ser correcto, de lo contrario, no se muestra bien o ni aparece. Por ejemplo un `<li>` tiene que ser hijo de un `<ul>` o un `<ol>`.